# Touch gestures recognition while screen is off?

Tags: android, kernel-module

I've been looking into on how to allow my phone to have it's screen off and allow it listen for touch gestures.

I've thought of doing loading kernel modules but as I read more about it I found out that it would be troublesome to do since I'd have to write one for multiple different kernels.

Does android sdk have anything that allows you to this easily? It would be really cool if you could just create a background service and listen for touch gestures even if the screen is off.

I'm just looking to see if this is possible without having to use kernel modules.

Comment: It probably isn't... and I'm not so sure it would be that useful to have my leg effectively doing gestures.

Comment: Android SDK don't support touch on lock/off screens by default, sorry